# Could not find the "Service webhook" section in portainer

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I could not find the "Service webhook" section in my portainer installation when I want to create a service in my docker swarm configuration
[Screenshot from portainer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP42n.png)
Where I can enable it?

Comment: what version of portainer are you using?

Comment: Check docs? https://docs.portainer.io/v/ce-2.11/user/docker/services/webhooks